# Alarm manager not working to show notification?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In my app I need to schedule daily notifications at specific time of the day. For this I am using the alarm manager to trigger the notification but it seems to be not working.

Below is my code for alarm manager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DietNotificationReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", "Alarm received");
    intent.putExtra("count", 12);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse("11:22 PM");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar cal = sdf.getCalendar();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

This is my broadcast class for handling notification

```
 public class DietNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "TBH")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Diet Now")
            .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("message"))
            .setLights(0xFFb71c1c, 1000, 2000)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(intent.getIntExtra("count", 0), builder.build());
}
}
```

I have added the receiver in manifest as well

```
<receiver
        android:name=".DietNotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Can you help me know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

so basically you are not using the correct way to set the specified time. set your time like this

```
Intent toastIntent = new Intent(this, DietNotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager backupAlarmMgr = (AlarmManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    long timeInterval = 6 * 1_000L;


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 38);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (backupAlarmMgr != null) {
        backupAlarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                timeInterval, pIntent);
    }
```